# How to get to the default laptop resolution after using external monitor?

Tags: laptop, display

I am using an external monitor but last week I went on vacation and when I turned on my laptop  and different programms they were just displayd outside of the laptop screen where I can't get to the window :D. For browser there is no such a problem. I am using Windows 7. Of course I tried to adjust the reselution settings, but it seems to be the right (highest and recommended) one. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and selecting the "Computer only" option.

Answer (score 0):

You mean your programs are out of sight?
[Offscreen Window - Bring it back to desktop](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/80519-offscreen-window-bring-back-desktop.html)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.